# Javascript - Search through the HTML of a site and replace it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscript

Well, just like my title says.
Is it possible to search through a whole page's HTML/CSS, and then replacing certain strings using JavaScript?

I tried to make something on my own but I'm doing it wrong.

```
var i, sig = document.getElementsByClassName('signaturecontainer');
for (i = 0; i < sig.length; i++)
{
    var str = sig[i].innerHTML;
    var n = str.replace(/< div style='250px;overflow:scroll;'/g, "< div > style='height:100%'");
}
```

Why I want to replace the string instead of using .innerHTML and just editing is due to that the div I want to change does not have an ID/Class.

This is what the line(s) I need changed:

> 

```
            <!-- edit note -->
            <blockquote class="postcontent lastedited">

                    Last edited by X; Today at <span class="time">06:32 AM</span>.


            </blockquote>
            <!-- / edit note -->



            <div style="height:250px;overflow: auto;"> // <--- This one.
                <blockquote class="signature restore"><div class="signaturecontainer">text here</div></blockquote>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Lots of ways, I'd imagine.  Can you provide a specific example of something you want to replace?  If the content is structured as DOM elements than they'll be very easy to manipulate.  If you need to identify specific text within a single DOM element then you can still do that with a little string manipulation.  (See MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Only if you specify a certain place to be searched, it will always search the entire page for the element you specify

Comment: I'm not sure if everything got into the script I posted as it removes lines with "< div>" without spaces etc.

Comment: Well, the first thing I notice there is that you're naming a variable `new`.  `new` is a reserved keyword.  (Hint: Using more meaningful variable names helps avoid this kind of collision.)  Once you fix that, in what way does this code not work as expected?  Are there any errors?

Comment: And well, if you look at the small snippet I posted, hopefully you will understand. If not; I'll try to explain better.
@David - Changed it to "n" instead.

Comment: At this point what are the runtime values of `str` and `n`?  It *looks* like you're trying to put the `style` attribute outside of the `div` element itself, and as content instead of markup.

Comment: @David - Well I want to replace an line on a site, but as it does not have an class/id (the element/div) I was going to try replacing the line, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

This line will give trouble:

```
    var new = str.replace(/< div style='250px;overflow:scroll;'/g, "< div > style='height:100%'");
```

- `new` is a reserved word. Change it to newstr, or whatever.
- Your regex pattern is unlikely to find anything: what it's searching for is not valid CSS
- The string you want to insert is not valid HTML/CSS. It should probably be `<div style='height:100%;'>`

It occurs to me that if you're just tweaking the styling then this is a clumsy way to go. You can change the styling directly with Javascript.

```
var i, sig = document.getElementsByClassName('signaturecontainer');
for (i = 0; i < sig.length; i++)
{
  sig[i].parentNode.style.height = "100%";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me as I have this line; <div style="height:250px;overflow: auto;">
Which I have no way of editing, hence why I want to use jScript. :p

Comment: Assuming that you're always editing a `<div>` that contains a `<blockquote>` with an identifiable class, you can select the parent node of the `<blockquote>` and adjust the style of that. I've tewaked my snippet accordingly.

Comment: Welp, now when I tried again, it kind of worked! :)
It adds a loooooooooooong row now, but it's almost as I want it.
To the left is one of the signatures, to the right is my scroll now. It added like 10000px or something, lol. As you can see here; http://puu.sh/4xVmS.jpg

Comment: edit @ ^; It will only do that if I do "reload and run" and it doesn't matter if I take 1% or 100%, it's the same height. :s

Answer (score 0):

We'll no it is not impossible, with JavaScript you can parse an HTML document by locating the tags is that you are trying to change. For example

```
    <div id="getThisChanged">change this text</div>
```

By executing this next line of JavaScript, you can change the text inside of the tag

```
            document.getElementById('getThisChanged').innerHTML("text is now changed");
```

The text will be changed to "text is now changed"

Comment: The problem is that why I need to search for the <div> string and replace it is due to it not having an id/class name :/